# Android--Mic input levels?

Tags: android

I want to detect blowing into the mic on android. Google wasn't much help. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK! I found this online, so it definitely seems possible. It looks like you can call mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude().

Code from an app called NoiseAlert

```
public void start() {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null"); 
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
        mEMA = 0.0;
    }
}

public double getAmplitude() {
    if (mRecorder != null)
        return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Here's the [source](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/SoundMeter.java?r=2)

Comment: I am getting error on 'mRecorder.prepare();' and when i add try catch block to it, error vanishes but runtime error occurs. Eagerly waiting for some good reply.

Comment: How can i continuously listen to the event in this case, I want the get Amplitude function to be triggered whenever there is a noise/sound.